# Cant run tests with pytest, module not found

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have a directory structured like this:

```
| project/
| ---- lib/
| -------- __init__.py
| -------- MyModule.py
| ---- test/
| -------- __init__.py
| -------- test_MyModule.py
| ---- __init__.py
```

in my test file i do the following:

```
from project.lib.MyModule import MyModule
```

This is the text of MyModule:

```
class MyModule(object):
    pass
```

I'm able to run this both in the console and from a file. But for some reason pytest is not able to discover `MyModule`. I get an error saying:

```
E   ImportError: No module named 'project'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've tried this too and failed:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "~/project")
```

Doesnt work. Help.

Comment: the `project` is not installed as a top-level module, so whether it works or not depends on what the current working directory is.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala how am i able to import it in other files then? as well as run it from the console?

Comment: also, the layout is somewhat unusual. One would rather use separate `src` and `test` directories, with `project` in `src` and make it correctly installable with `setup.py`

Comment: please detail how to solve the problem with a working example @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Also, `~/project` cannot work because `~` is expanded *only* in shells, it would never work in `sys.path`. (see `os.path.expanduser`)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala instead of pointing out what is wrong, please post a working solution

Answer (score 1):

It should be `from lib.MyModule import MyModule`

Comment: this doesnt work, im running pytest from the project root

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in your Python or pytest versions and/or platform (Windows/Linus distro).
My env:
`MacOS 10.11.6
Python 2.7.13
pytest (3.0.7)`

I recreated your project and couldn't repro your issue - pytest runs fine:

```
Dmitry[project]: tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── lib
│   ├── MyModule.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_MyModule.py

2 directories, 5 files
Dmitry[project]: cat lib/MyModule.py 
class MyModule(object):
    pass

Dmitry[project]: cat test/test_MyModule.py 
from project.lib.MyModule import MyModule

def test_object():
    o = MyModule()
    assert 1
```

run the pytest (for me it didn't matter where to run pytest from, just provide correct path to the dir with tests or test module):

```
Dmitry[project]: pytest -vvv test/test_MyModule.py 
================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
cachedir: .cache
sensitiveurl: .*
benchmark: 3.0.0 (defaults: timer=time.time disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=5.00us max_time=1.00s calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
rootdir: /private/tmp/project, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.15.0, variables-1.4, timeout-1.0.0, selenium-1.4.0, instafail-0.3.0, html-1.10.1, hidecaptured-0.1.2, excel-1.1.0, cov-2.5.1, capturelog-0.7, benchmark-3.0.0, base-url-1.1.0
collected 1 items 

test/test_MyModule.py::test_object PASSED

====================================================== 1 passed, 3 pytest-warnings in 0.02 seconds =======================================================
```